# Wordpress modify returned search results

Tags: wordpress, search

When I search on my wordpress site I want to filter the search results, namely, I want to remove the first line of each search result.

However wordpress returns the text with all newlines removed, just a chunk of text, so I can not decipher where the new lines are removed.

I tried overriding the

```
function wp_trim_excerpt($text)
```

Function, but the $text passed there already has new lines removed. Can someone point me in the right direction of where/when this happens so I can modify the function?

Comment: Essentially I need to know when  wp_trim_excerpt($text) is called by wordpress' search function.

Answer (score 1):

It's removed because the `loop.php` will use [`the_excerpt`()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) for searches and archives by default. Change it to `the_content()` or create / use your own custom function to return the search results in the format you want it in.